# Audio doesn't sound in a few iOS devices

Tags: ios, audio, mp3, avfoundation, avaudioplayer

I have developed an app that plays audio files with some voices recordings. When I debug it I have no problems with it, when I download it from the AppStore it works perfectly, my friends use it and they haven't got any problem with the app, but a few people from all over the world have contacted me to tell me that the app doesn't sound.

It is very strange because they tell me that the sound of the bell (mp3 44100Hz, mono, 128kbps) that plays first sounds but the voices (mp3 44100Hz, stereo, 96kbps) don't sound. The people that contact with me has different devices models and different versions of iOS 6.

I use AVAudioPlayer to play the files and I think that it work well.

Have you experienced the same problem?

Thank you

**UPDATE**

This is the Localizable.strings that I have

[image]

I load the file like this:

```
// 
NSString *fileLang = NSLocalizedString(aItem.fileName, nil);
//more code ...
thePlayerURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:fileLang   withExtension:@"mp3"];
//more code ...
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: aItem.urlAudio error:&error];
player.delegate = self;
[player prepareToPlay];
```

This is an example of the Localizable.strings with the file keys and values, by default the name of the key is the spanish version of the file:

```
//AUDIO NAMES

"1_au_es" = "1_au_en";
"2_au_es" = "2_au_en";
"3_au_es" = "3_au_en";
"4_au_es" = "4_au_en";
"5_au_es" = "5_au_en";
"6_au_es" = "6_au_en";
"7_au_es" = "7_au_en";
"8_au_es" = "8_au_en";
"9_au_es" = "9_au_en";
"10_au_es" = "10_au_en";
"11_au_es" = "11_au_en";
"12_au_es" = "12_au_en";
"13_au_es" = "13_au_en";
"14_au_es" = "14_au_en";
"15_au_es" = "15_au_en";
"16_au_es" = "16_au_en";
"17_au_es" = "17_au_en";
"18_au_es" = "18_au_en";
"19_au_es" = "19_au_en";
```

Comment: have you ensured that their vibrate button isn't flipped on? I wrote a translate app that had the users simply mute/put the vibrate button flipped on. It seems simple, but I've gotten almost 15 emails for that alone, no audio. lol

Comment: `AVAudioPlayer` uses the device's volume settings while `AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID` uses the system volume (eg. alert volume). Does the bell use the system sound API, while the rest uses `AVAudioPlayer`? They may have the sound muted or turned all the way down.

Comment: The bell audio plays perfectly so the vibrate button is flipped on :D

Comment: @torhector2, did you read my comment above? It explains why the bell may be playing but not the other.

Comment: If you turn off the sound the bell doesn't sound, I use AVAudioPlayer for the bell too :( Thank you Marcus

Comment: From which countries you are receiving these reports?

Comment: Can you write the audio filenames for us?

Comment: Hi @LuisEspinoza I have experienced problems in France, Denmark, Australia...

Comment: The files names are: 1_au_es.mp3 for spanish files, 1_au_en.mp3 for english files, 1_au_ge.mp3 for german files ... I load the names from the Localizable.strings, so maybe there is a problem with the localizable.strings. :/

Comment: Can you post another localization.string file, I suspecting that the format is not correct?

Comment: Can you add the code when you set aItem.fileName?

Comment: can you list the ios version which has problem? I am not sure if you paste the complete code, it seems that you need call [play] after [prepareToPlay]

Comment: I call the play method after the prepareToPlay :P

Comment: Are you using the "thePlayerURL" as I mentioned in my edited answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have you ensured that their vibrate button isn't flipped on? I wrote a translate app that had the users simply mute/put the vibrate button flipped on. It seems simple, but I've gotten almost 15 emails for that alone, saying the app had no audio.

It seems simple, but that solution is the easiest and quickest fix. Vibrate mode, turns off all audio, even for the apps.

My translate App used AVAudioPlayer, and there was nothing programmatically wrong. Just simply user error.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the audio bitrate could be the problem? I really don't know...

The bell, than works well has 128kbps and the audio files have 96kbps and sometimes don't work. The strange thing is that the audio works very well for the 90% of the uses but sometimes fail. The bell instead work well the 100% times.

:/

Answer (score 0):

Is very difficult to find the precise solution to this problem without checking your Xcode project configuration. However, by the information that you mentioned in the comments, I suspect that the problem must be related with the Localization strings. Check your localization configuration, check that you are using the localization strings files correctly, check that you wrote a valid filename for each supported localization.

Also, checking your code:

```
NSString *fileLang = NSLocalizedString(aItem.fileName, nil);
//more code ...
thePlayerURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:fileLang   withExtension:@"mp3"];
//more code ...
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: aItem.urlAudio error:&error];
player.delegate = self;
[player prepareToPlay];
```

Why you are not using "thePlayerURL"?. Maybe that is the problem, since is the "Localized URL". I would expect:

```
NSString *fileLang = NSLocalizedString(aItem.fileName, nil);
//more code ...
thePlayerURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:fileLang   withExtension:@"mp3"];
//more code ...
AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:thePlayerURL error:&error];
player.delegate = self;
[player prepareToPlay];
```

Comment: The strange thing is that I have tested all the languages and audios, and all works perfectly in my devices, but there are some people that have problems.

Comment: How are you handling localization in your project?, You have multiple string files?

Comment: Are you using just one .string file?

Comment: I have one Localizable.string bundle with one file per language. The I transform the name of the Localizable.strings to NSUrl.

Comment: Yes, 1_au_es is the key in the strings file to the first audio file. Then with NSLocalizedString macro I get the localized version of that key, that is 1_au_en or 1_au_ge or 1_au_jp... The default value is the key: 1_au_es

Comment: Which is the value of the "Localization native development region" in your project?

Comment: Ok, so when you try your app, you load the Localization.string(English) that looks just like the spanish file?

Comment: The spanish version is like that: "1_au_es" = "1_au_es"; and so on

Comment: I edited my answer again, since I noticed something suspicious in your code

Comment: Hi Luis, yes I use thePlayerUrl, before that piece of code I do this: aItem.urlAudio = thePlayerURL; then  AVAudioPlayer *player = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL: aItem.urlAudio error:&error];

Answer (score 0):

I recently submitted an application that was having the same problems, but it was denied due to the fact that I hadn't setup "Inter-App Audio" in Xcode and in the Certificates pane under the app info. That may help.

In case you are wondering, the application was in violation of *Section 2.13* of the [App Store Guidelines.](http://www.cultofmac.com/58590/heres-the-full-text-of-apples-new-app-store-guidelines/)

Comment: I hadn't setup "Inter-App Audio" in Xcode and in Developer portal, but I have "App plays audio" in Requiered Background modes. :/

Comment: Isn't the "Inter-App Audio" a feature for iOS 7? My app is iOS6